# How to make a link of .headline.img-headline

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Would anyone know how to make a link out of the .headline.img-headline on my home page? I tried to change it in home-page-small.php.

From:

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
    <div class="feature-img page-banner" <?php if ( ! empty( $thumb ) ) { ?> style="background-image: url(<?php echo esc_url( $thumb[0] ); ?>);" <?php } ?>>
    <h2 class="headline img-headline"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'giving-featured-small' ); ?>
```

To:

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
    <div class="feature-img page-banner" <?php if ( ! empty( $thumb ) ) { ?> style="background-image: url(<?php echo esc_url( $thumb[0] ); ?>);" <?php } ?>>
    <h2 class="headline img-headline"><a href="MY LINK" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'giving-featured-small' ); ?>
```

But I am not sure if that is the right place to be.

Comment: You need to tell us a little bit more... what php system/framework/cms are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your reaction! Using Wordpress. I also tried using the following to the page.php template;  <?php if(is_home() ) {
 echo "<a href='MY LINK'>MY TITLE</a>";
} else { the_title(); } ?>